# Not all Android apps auto-update

Tags: android

We've developed an Android tablet app going out on Google Play. Client has purchased 100 Lenovo Tab 2 A10s and installed this on them but when the latest version of the app was published it hasn't updated on the devices.  The settings in both the Google Play app page and the Google Play Settings page are set correctly.

I have seen that Google says that updates can take up to 24 hours to be pushed to devices, however it's now well and truly over that time period.  I've looked at other apps in the Google Play 'My Apps' section and can see there are a number (all set to 'auto-update') but not updated on the device, even though an update is available.  One app I can see goes back to end of October and still hasn't updated.  Am I missing something or is this the norm on Google Play and apps could take even weeks to update even if set to auto-update?

N.B: I've found many old posts about developers trying to get their auto updates to work on their private apps but not specific to my issue so have posted this.

Comment: Make sure the tablets are connected to WiFi, if they are connected via cellular it likely won't update. It could also be a bug with the Lenovo OEM software.

Comment: Device only has wifi and wifi signal is quite strong.